# Is there a way to check if use is admin when using OAuth2 instead of OpenId?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

We are migrating out applications from OpenID using UserService to OAuth2 / OpenID Connect to move our apps to the new Google Apps Marketplace.
We are using UserService.isAdmin() to check if a user is registered as admin for the GAE application.
How can we keep this functionality when moving to OAuth2 for login?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can explicitly check who the admin is any other way.

It is rare that you would need to know the App Engine admin in a publicly-listed app. If the app is a general solution app, than aren't you the admin? Most developers care about the Domain Admin, which can be determined with the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users). If these is just for your own use, set the visibility options to your domain in the Chrome Webstore Developer Dashboard.